# stop benching at al-yichasiranu?

Tags: halacha, bentching

Can you stop benching (saying the grace after a meal) after *al-yichasiranu* (the end of the fourth blessing of the grace)?

Answer (score 5):

The mechaber brings "harahaman"s as an optional addition to Bircas HaMazone. Today the general Ashkenazic Minhag is to say it all unless you have one of the following two minhagim:

1. The GRA holds that on Shabbos one should stop before the personal requests  (yifarnisanu bchavod).
2. In Slobodka Yeshivah (hence in Chaim Berlin) the custom was to stop at Al Yihasireinu so as to gain a few more minutes for learning Torah. Those who still have this custom either descend from those who learned/taught there or picked it up in Yeshivah.

Comment: Students of Rabbi Chait's Yeshiva stop at the al yechasireinu on Shabbos, for the reason mentioned above. Not being one, I'm not sure what they do the rest of the week.

Comment: Which Rabbi Chait? And why at "Al Yihasireinu" if the first few Harahamans are not personal requests?

Comment: I know the GR"A held you can't say them on Shabbath, but I also heard it said that he didn't say them at all, and for the reason mentioned in 2. Could this be true, or was my source confused about where that tradition originated?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is also a source [help please!] that says, while on your employer's time, you should only say the first four berachot. this could be extended to other situations where time or kavana are limited.

Comment: See Shulchan Aruch OC Siman 191

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your minhag. Some do, some don't.

Comment: cHAIM bERLINERS

Comment: I guess this about as a good an answer as the question was.